# After Upgrading to 5.23.0 New Cases Missing Custom Field Data from Webform Submission

Tags: webform-civicrm, core

I have a Drupal webform which creates a new case in Civi. After upgrading from 5.22.1 to 5.23.0 all the custom field data in the case is missing after submitting the webform. There are no error messages either in Civi or in Drupal.

I have duplicated the issue to make sure it was the upgrade that was causing the problem.

I am using Drupal 7.67 with the latest version of Webform_CiviCRM.

Comment: As this is related to the Webform_CiviCRM module I have created an issue for this in that module's issue queue at https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm/issues/3121142

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a core bug, have logged an [issue](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/1695) and provided temporary fix for it on the [ticket](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/1695).

Comment: That's great! Thanks very much for responding and for the fix.